# Mac trying to play audio through monitor's thunderbolt port

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, audio, display, thunderbolt

I have a Dell monitor connected through a thunderbolt port.

Sometimes my Mac for some reason is attempting to play audio through that port.  How do I stop this from happening?

It appears in my list of sound outputs in system preferences but I have headphones selected.  Unplugging the monitor from the thunderbolt port makes the audio work correctly.

Comment: It thinks you have a Video+Audio device (like TV) plugged in :) do you ? what does it say for what is plugged in?

Comment: I found the issue.  I was using GarageBand and it has it's own setting for audio out separate from System Preferences.

Comment: nice job, make it a answer !

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me. You have to manually change it in System Preferences > Sound > Output Volume.

Answer (score 1):

Alt-click the audio item in the menu bar and select the proper source.